# App Engine nodejs with automatic scaling not going to zero instances with no traffic

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy an app engine on google cloud with the following app.yaml :

```yaml
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
entrypoint: node app.js
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 0
  min_idle_instances: 0
  cool_down_period_sec: 180
```

I would expect active instances to go down to 0 when there is no traffic (I accept initial warmup latency)
Obviously i keep seeing at least 2 active instances running.
What am i missing, thank you !

I implemented warmup routes (doing nothing) with no impact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Flex. Flex can't go down to 0 instances i.e. it can't scale to zero (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#compare_high-level_features))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, the documentation has multiple URLs concerning app engine not always saying the same thing.

i changed my app.yaml like this and it looks like it's working as expected now

```yaml
runtime: nodejs18

entrypoint: node app.js
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 0
  min_idle_instances: 0
```